# How can I find the time difference in days between the current date and a future date in C?

Tags: c, date

I am trying to find the number of days between the current date and a given future date. From what I've read so far I can use the built in date type `struct tm` and this is what I tried but I just can't get it to work. Every time I use it I get some junk like `-1615574208.000000`. I'll give one of the many examples that I tried. Here I am trying to find the time difference between today and tomorrow at midnight.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm current_date = *localtime(&t);    // get the current date information
    struct tm away_date;

    // now we set the away date information
    away_date.tm_year = 2021;
    away_date.tm_mon = 3;
    away_date.tm_mday = 13;
    away_date.tm_hour = 23;
    away_date.tm_min = 59;
    away_date.tm_sec = 59;

    // now we make both of these of type time_t so we can use difftime()
    time_t t1, t2;
    t2 = mktime(&away_date);
    t1 = mktime(&current_date);

    // now we find the difference
    double diff = difftime(t2, t1);
    printf("%f\n", diff);

    return 0;
}
```

As I said, this doesn't work. When I run it I get `-1615574757.000000`. Something is obviously wrong, but I can't figure out what. I've been searching and trying all kind of versions of the above code, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please read the docs: member `tm_year` is "years since 1900". Also `tm_month` is zero based, so March (today) would be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not junk, it is the number of seconds since the start of the UNIX epoch - 1970 (about 51 years).

`t2` is likely zero because you set the `tm_year` out of range at 3921 (1900+2021). There is no defined limit on `tm_year` other then that imposed by its data type, but on a system with a 32 bit `time_t`, 19 January 2038 is quite literally the *end of time*.

Always look at the inputs before declaring a function does not work - garbage-in, garbage-out.  As well at `tm_year` being an offset from 1900, note that `tm_mon` starts from January == 0, so your `away_date` is in April, which may not be what you expected either.